# How to authorize user between each step in Multi-Factor-Authentication?

Tags: authentication, multi-factor

Assume an authentication process that has multiple stages ( eg: username/password then OTP)

How you can authorize and identify user between each steps? If JWT tokens are used, is it an option to use different secrets to generate token for each steps?

Is there any standards for the above process

Comment: Do you mean how can you confirm the same user is at each step?

Comment: Yes.. for example, when you log-in to your gmail with 2FA, first password is asked. then the password is comformed and OTP sent. Next you are asked to enter OTP. So, my question is how do you authorize/authenticate the user at the second stage as no username or password is provided.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

By giving them a session. The entire idea of a session is that a client receives some kind of number, which they give back to you upon every request. You will then have to decide how you deal with that number, and if you authorize this request.

As soon as they correctly enter their credentials, you can give them a session. That doesn't mean that that session is authorized to do anything yet, just that you are in the process of authenticating them.

Once the second factor authenticated them as well, you can mark the session as authorized to do whatever the user is authorized to do (e.g. creating a post, upvoting something, etc.).

If a user were attempting to perform such an action with a session that was not fully authorized (e.g. they did not enter the PIN sent via SMS), then they should receive the same error as a user who did not have a session at all.

Answer (score 1):

Return a JWT as each factor is authenticated, but use a unique 'aud' claim that is only used for that step. Set the 'exp' claim to have a short expiry, say 5 minutes. Ensure all consumers of the final JWT are verifying the 'aud' claim.

Comment: Got it. But explain me should we use two different `JWT secrets` for each step?

Comment: I think using an asymmetric algorithm is safer, like RS256. You can definitely use the same signing key for both.